# How to preserve empty rows when importing xlsx files into R with read.xlsx?

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to import xlsx files of varying lengths into R. I'm currently using the function read.xlsx from R's xlsx package to import the xlsx files into R, and unfortunately it drops empty rows. Is there a way that I can import every row of an xlsx file up until the last row with content without dropping empty rows?

Comment: `readxl::read_excel` does the job.

Answer (score 6):

That package has not been updated since 2014 ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html), though it looks like there has been some work in 2017 at https://github.com/dragua/xlsx), I suggest either [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) or [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html):

```
readxl::read_excel("file_with_blank_row.xlsx")
openxlsx::read.xlsx("file_with_blank_row.xlsx", skipEmptyRows=FALSE)
```

Minor update (Mar 2024): the [`xlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) package was updated on CRAN on 2020-11-10, and while there was [some activity](https://github.com/colearendt/xlsx/commits/main/) in 2022, it does not seem to have come to fruition. I don't know if the OP's issues remain, but I still recommend one of [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html), [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html), or a newcomer to the fray, [`openxlsx2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx2/index.html), a modernization effort for the `openxlsx` package.

Comment: Was this sufficient, J0HN_TIT0R? Was there something else with your question?

Answer (score 1):

As noted by r2evans, both `readxl` and `openxlsx` have options to turn off skipping of empty rows. However, regardless of those switches, they will *silently drop leading empty rows*.

`openxlsx` doesn't seem to offer the possibility of altering that behaviour.

`readxl` has a `range` parameter that will indeed keep **all** empty rows. This is necessary if you're hoping to edit the same Excel file in very specific locations.

You need to have something like `readxl::read_excel("path_to_your.xlsx", range = cell_limits(c(1, NA), c(NA,NA))`. Using NA for all values apparently causes the function to revert to default and drop leading empty rows.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
library("readxl")
my_data <- read_xlsx("file_with_blank_row.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is the same as the previous answer, but without any supporting information